# screen doesn't show, Console.ReadLine() in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm using GHC 8.6.5 in Windows 10.

I'm a beginner in Haskell, but have some C# experience. When I try
`main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"` and I compile, the program shows the screen only for a moment. I want something like `Console.ReadLine()` in C# so that the screen will remain until I press enter. What should I do?

I have searched the net for 2 hours in vain.

```
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: While learning Haskell, you can also use GHCi, which is a REPL, and load your `.hs` file, avoiding `main`. In GHCi you can evaluate any expression and observe their result. If you edit the `.hs` file, you can use `:r` to reload the new definitions.

Comment: Next time, use [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=getLine) to search for library functions.

Comment: There is no Haskell 8.6.5. If you mean ghc 8.6.5, say so.

Answer (score 3):

`getLine` reads a whole line (returning that as a string, but you don't need that).

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Hello, World!"
   getLine
```

In this way, you'll need to press enter to exit the program.

Comment: Side note: this relies on a small quirk of `main`, that its type is allowed to be `IO x` for any type `x`, and the result is simply ignored. To discard the result of `getLine` explicitly, you can write `main :: IO (); do { putStrLn "..."; _ <- getLine; pure () }` or `void getLine` using `void` from `Control.Monad`.